Question about derivation of complex inner products
Let $X$ be a (seperable) Hilbert space with the inner product $ \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_X$ and $v: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow H$. Now the following applies in real Hilbert spaces $$\frac{d}{dt} \vert\vert v\vert\vert^2= \frac{d}{dt}\langle v,v\rangle_X =2 \langle \frac{d}{dt} v,v\rangle_X.$$ Now the last equality is only valid due to the symmetry of real inner products and should therefore fail for complex inner products due to the lack of symmetry and the transformation should therefore be invalid. Is my assumption correct?

Yes you are correct. The formula is invalid, because $\langle u,v\rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$ for complex $v,u$.
In fact, Let $v:\mathbb{C}\to H$, then $$\frac{d}{dt}\|v\|^2=\frac{d}{dt}\langle v,v\rangle_X=\langle\frac{d}{dt}v,v\rangle_X+\langle v,\frac{d}{dt}v\rangle_X=\langle\frac{d}{dt}v,v\rangle_X+\overline{\langle\frac{d}{dt}v,v\rangle_X}=2Re\left(\langle\frac{d}{dt}v,v\rangle_X\right)$$
